# How to automatically populate a gallery with images attached to posts of one category?

Tags: images, gallery

I would like to have a gallery in a post or a page (code in template or via shortcode). The images of this gallery should be pulled automatically from posts of one or more categories of my choice.

So as soon as a new post is saved all images (one or more) attached to this post should automatically be added to the gallery.

It'd be perfect if this gallery could be placed on a separate page. 
If a plugin does the trick: fine, too.

Comment: thanks for respomdimg. I havn't tried anything really, yet. I'm not a programmer, so I searched for a code snippet or a plugin which would do the trick.
The only thing I found after days of searching is "complety gallery manager" (premium).
Regards
stephan

Comment: Stephan, please use the comments to clarify other users doubts, or edit the Question to add new information relevant to it. Reading the FAQ will enhance your further use of this site.

Answer (score 1):

In form of a shortcode to render a default WordPress `[gallery]` shortcode including all attachments of the given categories:

```
/**
 * Usage: [catgallery cat="4,5"]
 * Attribute: array of category IDs
 */

add_shortcode('catgallery', 'wpse_70989_cat_gallery_shortcode');

function wpse_70989_cat_gallery_shortcode($atts) 
{
    // $return = ''; // DEBUG: enable for debugging
    $arr = array();
    $cat_in = explode( ',', $atts['cat'] );
    $catposts = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page'    => -1
    ,   'category__in'      => $cat_in
    ) );

    foreach( $catposts->posts as $post)
    {

        // DEBUG: Enable the next line to print the post title
        // $return .= '<strong>' . $post->post_title . '</strong><br />';

        $args = array( 
            'post_type'     => 'attachment'
        ,   'numberposts'   => -1
        ,   'post_status'   => null
        ,   'post_parent'   => $post->ID 
        ); 
        $attachments = get_posts($args);

        if ($attachments) 
        {
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) 
            {
                // DEBUG: Enable the next line to debug the attachement object
                // $return .= 'Attachment:<br /><pre>' . print_r($attachment, true) . '</pre><br />';
                $arr[] = $attachment->ID;
            }
        }

    }
    // DEBUG: Disable the next line if debugging 
    $return = do_shortcode( '[gallery include="' . implode( ',', $arr ) . '"]' );
    return $return;
}
```

Read the documentation to fine tune the code to your specs.

- [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class
- [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts)
- [`do_shortcode`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode)
- [Gallery Shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode)

Comment: Thank you so much brasofilo an sorry for nut using the commetn function (twice...!). Got it now. ;) I insertet your code into my functions php file and wrote a post with [catgallery cat="1"]: nothing happens. Any hints for a non-programmer/beginner? Thanks again! Stephan

Comment: Sorry Stephan, there was a mistake in the code when extracting the categories IDs from the shortcode. It has to be converted to array as it comes as a string. :::: Anyway, replace it in full in your `functions.php`. And follow the `DEBUG` instructions in the code to check what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: thanks again! Unfortunately, nothing shows up, when I replace the code in my functions.php file. When I add a post with "[catgallery cat="1"]" (or cat="48" or whatever) the shortcode itself is displayed in the post. that's it. Also, removing the  // for debuggung has no effekt, .

Comment: If the shortcode itself is being printed, the `add_shortcode` function is not being called... Are you sure is the right `functions.php`? :::: **Or**: create a new PHP file, put a basic [plugin header information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Standard_Plugin_Information), paste the code, upload to your plugins folder and activate.

Comment: Here we go: :) 1) SORRY: I made a small but vital mistake while pasting your code, I double checked and found my mistake: now images are showing up! 2) THAAAAANK YOU!!! 3) one (hopefully) last question: it seems only newly added posts with images and existing featured images are added. is it possible to add attached images of already existing posts? regards Stephan

Comment: There's nothing in this code that would limit the listing to only *"newly added"* posts... And if you add an image to an existing post, **it has** to show up immediately in the `catgallery` shortcode output...

Comment: **THANK YOU! EVERYTHING WORKS PERFECTLY!** I was missing 2 images. but my friend inserted them ("inline") instead of attaching them...that's all. best wishes stephan